# Recieve HTTP POST from AJAX, and read it in backend java

Tags: java, javascript, json, http

I am making a ticket-system. Frontend is javacript/angular, sending HTTP requests with ajax.
How we do it now is put the parameters in the header, something like this:

```
  numbPass: 3
  Total Price: 39
```

This is saved under ONE order, but 3 passengers. The price for each passenger can be different, ex regular, student, military. So to split the total amount on 3 is not an option.

The variables is today recieved in backend like this:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
 WalkIn walkinRequest = gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), WalkIn.class);
```

What I want is to send lists of the passengers, and I found out that this is possible like this:

```
var schedule = [];
    var passenger = { 
      type : 'student', 
      price' : 150,
    }
    schedule.push(passenger);

    var passenger = { 
      type : 'student', 
      'price' : 150,
    }
    schedule.push(passenger);
```

But how do I  process this data in backend using java (put them in passenger-objects)?

edit: It may be hard to understand what I ask for. first of I wanted to know if gson handle the processing of arrays from HTTP-requests. If not, then I want to know how to solve this. 
The question is answered in a post below.

Comment: You mean to say you want `student`, `150`, etc from JSON as `String`, `int`, etc. & set it in setter methods or use somewhere else in Java code ?

Comment: That is correct. Does gson handle list-parameters??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to guess what you mean, by your question.

1. If it's simple deserialization question, than in Gson you can read array of objects like this:

   ```
   WalkIn[] walkinRequests = gson.fromJson(req.getReader(), WalkIn[].class);
   ```
2. If you want to change your WalkIn structure from:

   ```
   WalkIn
       int numbPass
       int totalPrice
   ```

   to

   ```
   WalkIn
       PassengerWalkIn[]
       int numbPass
       int totalPrice

   PassengerWalkIn
       String type
       int price
   ```

   than GSON is capable of deserializing this as is.